# How to pass useState value to another component compare

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jsx, styled-components

Im trying to achive background blur effect when another component appears.

I have Language Slider component and its Renders `onClick={openLang}` mentioned below.

```
const [lang, setLang] = useState(1)

const openLang = (index) => {
  setLang((index => index + 1))
}
```

so I  trying to do next:

```
{lang / 2 === 1 ? styles={{filter: 'blur(10px)' : styles={{backgroun: '#F4F4F4'}}
```

I cant figure how to get lang value to another component where neither compnent is not child or parent.

Comment: You can use Context. Read more: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: Thank you  @ Amirhossein, @Dream-Bold

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `useContext` to implement your idea. Here's the live demo for `useContext`

https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-borg-eox8qp?file=/src/App.js